# An adjective meaning "plays a crucial role" [in]

Tags: single-word-requests

Which adjective can function as a synonym for "plays a crucial role" [in]? I remember there is one, but I can't recall it....

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence?  Otherwise, this question may be closed.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As @Nathaniel commented, that is the rule here. ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

Consider **instrumental**:

> involved in an important way in making something happen
>
> Example: *an instrumental figure in the governor’s campaign for re-election*

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/instrumental_1))

Answer (score 1):

There is ['pivotal'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pivotal?s=t)

> pivotal - **adjective**
>
> 2 - of vital or critical importance: *a pivotal event*.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

There is also ['central'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/central?s=t)

> central - **adjective**
>
> 3 - constituting something from which other related things proceed or upon which they depend: *a central office*.
>
> 4 - principal; chief; dominant: *the play's central character*.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

***key***?

> : of crucial importance : *she became a key figure in the suffragette movement* [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/key)

Answer (score 0):

The adjective ***[critical](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/critical)*** has several meanings, among them, "**vital**," "verging on emergency," "tending to point out errors," and "careful."

> If you're an emergency-room doctor with a patient in **critical**
>   condition (on the highest alert), it's absolutely critical (vital or
>   essential) that you be **critical** (careful and judicious) in your
>   approach to their care, so that at the **critical** (decisive) moment, you
>   can save their life.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/critical))

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[integral](http://tfd.com/integral)**

> of or belonging as an essential part of the whole; necessary to completeness; constituent: an integral part.